Adding style when bootstrap collapse open
I want to add a style to the opened div for my Bootstrap-collapse.
My code:
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree2">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree2">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree2" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree2" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree4">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree4" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree4">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

<script>
    
$('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function(e) {
  var $card = $(this).closest('.card');
  var $open = $($(this).data('parent')).find('.collapse.show');
  
  var additionalOffset = 70;
  if($card.prevAll().filter($open.closest('.card')).length !== 0)
  {
        additionalOffset =  $open.height();
  }
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $card.offset().top - additionalOffset
  }, 500);
});
</script>

When every collapse been open, I want to add this styling to card-header
style="margin-top: 60px;"

I have try this code, but no styling adding to the card-header div. And when I added this code the scrollTo-function also stop working. If I remove "document.getElementById($card).style.margin-top = "60px";" the scrollTo-function working again.
<script>
    
$('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function(e) {
  var $card = $(this).closest('.card');
  var $open = $($(this).data('parent')).find('.collapse.show');
  
  var additionalOffset = 70;
  if($card.prevAll().filter($open.closest('.card')).length !== 0)
  {
        additionalOffset =  $open.height();
  }
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $card.offset().top - additionalOffset,
    document.getElementById($card).style.margin-top = "60px";
  }, 500);
});
</script>


Please create a minimal reproducible example
